# How to replace value with another value using Jquery Ajax in mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

Hi I am using Ajax Jquery to pass the promotional code to the controller ,
check the code , do some calculation and return the result , What I want to do 
is to replace the total result on page with the new result , Below is the code:

```
("#deduct").click(function () {
        var codenumber = $('#codeText').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',    
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            data: {input:$('#codeText').val() },
             success: function (result) {
            alert(result.name);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
        });
        return false;
    });


     <div class="totalCost">
                   <label><b>Amount:</b></label> <%: String.Format("{0:c}", ViewBag.TotalAmount)%> <br /></div> // Want to replace ViewBag.TotalAmount with json result
                   <div class="promo">
                   <%:Html.ActionLink("promo", "Deduct", "Booking", null, new { id = "deduct" })%><input type="text" name="" id="codeText" />

                   </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Deduct(string input)
    {
        IVoucherRepository voucherResp = new VoucherRepository();
        IQueryable<Voucher> getVoucher = voucherResp.GetAllVouchers();
        //first check if the code is there or not else return error

        if (input == "")
        {
            return Json(new { name = "Please Enter the Promo Code" });
        }
        else if (getVoucher.Any(r => r.Code == input))
        {
            foreach (var validCode in getVoucher)
            {
                if (validCode.DiscountType == 1)
                {
                    decimal discount = Convert.ToDecimal(TempData["test"]) - validCode.Discount;
                    return Json(new { name =  discount });
                }
                //" Valid Code " + " Total Discount : " + validCode.Discount + " Discount Type : (£) " + " Final Price : " +

            }
            return Json(new { name = "" });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { name = "Invalid Code Entered" });
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where do you set `TempData["test"]`, and to what?

Comment: well I want to replace  ViewBag.TotalAmount with the result in the view

Comment: TempData["test"] is coming from another action method and its value is in decimal

Comment: i tried something like this with no success : success: function (result) {
                alert(result.name);
                var totalamount = $(result);
                $('.totalcost').append(totalamount);
            },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr A,

You need to give your amount field an id to work with. something along the lines of the following may work:

```
<div class="totalCost">
  <label><b>Amount:</b></label><p id="newTotal"><!--existing stuff--></p> <br />
</div>
```

(you probably won't even need the `<br />` above if you use the `<p>`)

and in your jquery code:

```
success: function (result) {
        $('#newTotal').val(result.name);
}
```

that would be the 1st thing i'd try.

Comment: thnx jim dat didnt solved d whole issue but leads me to d ryt direction ..:)